# .NET Core 2 Benchmarking, req/s far below what's expected

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, benchmarking

I was running an arbitrary benchmark on an empty .NET Core web app today and was disappointed at how low the req/s numbers consistently were. I've seen [examples](https://medium.com/@tampajohn/net-core-2-and-golang-797566350095) online where people are getting 50-60k req/s, [some](https://www.ageofascent.com/2016/02/18/asp-net-core-exeeds-1-15-million-requests-12-6-gbps/) as crazy as 1.15M req/s, and mine clock in between 1-2.5k.

#### My machine specs:

[image]

#### Code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.IO;
namespace NetCore
{
  public class Startup
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
      app.Run(async (context) =>
      {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Which I'm running using the **release** configuration, targeting `netcoreapp2.1`:

```
dotnet publish -c release -f netcoreapp2.1
```

And I'm benchmarking using bombardier:

```
bombardier http://localhost:5000 -c 250 -d 30s
```

#### Results:

[image]

Just wondering whether I'm missing something obvious here. Or doing something wrong.

To track, I've posted an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1899) on GitHub.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot some prewarming requests?

Comment: Just rebooted the web server, hit it with a few warming requests. And it actually got worse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might have console logging at `Information` level? (There are also faster forms of logging)

Try switching reducing it to `Warning` off by adding a `appsettings.json` file

`{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}`

Also ensure you are using Server GC; the top of your `.csproj` should have `.Web` at the end

`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`

Also you are running the published dll?

`dotnet bin\release\netcoreapp2.1\publish\myapp.dll`

Comment: I have dumbfounded and amazed at how detrimental the console logging was. The req/s are now up over 70k req/s. Thank you Ben!

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:  Your CPU is i7-7500U @2.70G @2.90G

1. Here the letter `U` in the `i7-7500U` stands for `Ultra Low Voltage` , which means your CPU is not that powerful even compared with a Core i4 with the letter HQ , HK , or no letter at all .
2. Note that those benchmarking online often use a more powerful CPU . For example , the [Benchmarking here](https://hackernoon.com/iris-go-vs-net-core-kestrel-in-terms-of-http-performance-806195dc93d5) , which processes 97.9K req/sec , use a processor of `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7–4710HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz 2.50GHz`.
3. I don't think the benchmarking matters or not . Because we'll always have different hardware, different OS , different processes running , and different networks . However , just as a example to prove that CPU does matters , I paste the bencnmarking of your code on My computer (Core(TM) i7-4900 @3.6GHz @3.6GHz ) as below :

   ```
   >bombardier.exe  http://localhost:5000 -c 250 -d 30s
   Bombarding http://localhost:5000 for 30s using 250 connection(s)
   ```

   [=================================================================================================================] 30s

   Done!

   Statistics        Avg      Stdev        Max

   eqs/sec      9625.47    1759.59   13165.59

   Latency       25.94ms   498.77us    73.96ms

   HTTP codes:

   1xx - 0, 2xx - 289210, 3xx - 0, 4xx - 0, 5xx - 0

   others - 0

   Throughput:     1.70MB/s

Comment: Though I will accept that the CPU is low-voltage. A similar test with Go, yielded 250k req/s. So I don't think that's the only culprit here. Following Ben's advice from above solved the issue, and kicked up the performance to ~70k req/s

Comment: @pimbrouwers  I'm confused now. My benchmarking above is done with a default logging level setting at `Warning` .  I'll test it later . Thanks